# Tight subplot with colorbars and subplot's 3rd parameter in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, subplot, colorbar

I would like to have a tight subplot i.e. minimum spacing between figures in the subplot where

- you have subplot's 3rd parameter i.e. you can decide where the picture is going to be i.e. easy to move between `subplot` and `new_tight_subplot`, and
- you can use it with colorbars.

I have profiled the most popular tight subplots in FileExchange of Matlab. 
None (etc most popular [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27991-tight-subplot) Pekka's version) can pass the following code

```
data=randi(513,513); 

ax1=subplot(2,1,1); 
plot(mat2gray(pdist(data, 'correlation')));
cbar1=colorbar(ax1);
axis(ax1, 'square');
xlim([0 size(mat2gray(pdist(data, 'correlation')),2)]);
set(cbar1, 'Visible', 'off')

ax2=subplot(2,1,2); 
imshow(squareform( mat2gray(pdist(data, 'correlation')), 'tomatrix') ); 
colormap('parula'); colorbar;
axis(ax2, 'square');
```

Pekka's `tight_subplot` requires the syntax without the third parameter. 
It also fails with colorbars as in the example. I do not understand why.

### Hypothesis about the 2nd problem with colorbars

I think the problem can be the fact that colorbar objects are children of the figure, not axis, and their position is defined in normalized figure units; like for annotated objects as discussed [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/334927). 
However, I am unsure how to adjust the tight subplot for this.

### Test output after Author's edit in tight_subplot in FileExchange 3.3.2016

Code

```
data = randi(513, 513); 

ax1=tight_subplot(2,1,[.01 .03],[.1 .01],[.01 .01]); 
plot(mat2gray(pdist(data, 'correlation')));

ax2=tight_subplot(2,1,[.01 .03],[.1 .01],[.01 .01]); 
imshow(squareform( mat2gray(pdist(data, 'correlation')), 'tomatrix') );
```

You get

[image]

where the `plot` fails and there is noisy part in the second figure for some reason. Why?

### Extension of Suever's answer to 2x2 figures

```
ax1=axes('OuterPosition', [0 0.5 0.5 0.5]);
plot(u, 'Parent', ax1);
set(ax1, 'XLim', [0, size(u,1)]);
cbar1 = colorbar(); % not needed to assign ax1
set(cbar1, 'Visible', 'off')

ax3 = axes('OuterPosition', [0 0 0.5 0.5]);
image(data, 'Parent', ax3);

D=mat2gray(pdist(pTFD, 'correlation'));

ax2 = axes('OuterPosition', [0.51 0.5 0.5 0.5]);
plot(D, 'Parent', ax2);
set(ax2, 'XLim', [0, size(D,1)])
axis(ax2, 'square');
xlim([0 size(D,2)]);
set(cbar2, 'Visible', 'off')

ax4 = axes('OuterPosition', [0.51 0 0.5 0.5]);
imshow( D_square ); 
axis(ax4, 'square');
```

where 2x2 figure system and where I think equivalent

- `xlim([0 size(D,2)]);` is same as `set(ax1, 'XLim', [0, size(D,2)]);`. Right?
- ...

---

How can you use Matlab's tight subplot with colorbars and third parameter?

Comment: what do you understand by "tight"? What exactly does no work with which functions? Please post an executable example and a screenshot of what you want.

Comment: @thewaywewalk I defined tight. I provided example data in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to deal with `subplot` and different versions on the file exchange, I would probably just manually set the positions of my axes objects to get the effect that you want. You can use normalized units so that the positions scale as the size of the parent figure changes.

Also, you can set the `OuterPosition` property of the axes which takes into account the room needed to properly display all text labels of the axes.

```
figure

data=randi(513,513);

set(0, 'defaultaxeslooseinset', [0 0 0 0])

D = mat2gray(pdist(data, 'correlation'));
square = squareform(D, 'tomatrix');

% Set normalized outer position (x,y,width,height)
ax1 = axes('OuterPosition', [0, 0.5, 1, 0.5]);
plot(D, 'Parent', ax1);
set(ax1, 'XLim', [0, size(square, 1)])
axis(ax1, 'square');

cbar1 = colorbar();
set(cbar1, 'Visible', 'off')

% Set normalized outer position (x,y,width,height)
ax2 = axes('OuterPosition', [0 0 1 0.5]);
imshow(square);
colormap('parula'); colorbar;
axis(ax2, 'square');
```

[image]

And if you remove the x and y ticks on the axes

```
set([ax1,ax2], 'xtick', [], 'ytick', []);
```

[image]

This can easily be adapted to any dimensions with something similar to the following

```
figure;
% [Rows, Columns]
axdim = [3, 3];

width = 1 ./ axdim(2);
height = 1./ axdim(1);

[x,y] = meshgrid(linspace(0,1,axdim(2)+1), ...
                 linspace(0,1, axdim(1)+1));

for k = 1:numel(x)
    ax = axes('OuterPosition', [x(k), y(k), width, height]);
    set(ax, 'xtick', [], 'ytick', []);
end
```

Comment: I extended your answer to 2x2 figure system. See the body. Assume you want next 3x3 figure system. Would you just choose values relative values by trial-and-error and counting?

Comment: @Masi you can compute *exactly* what they will need to be. I have updated my answer to include the general case at the end.

Answer (score 2):

The third parameter of `tight_subplot` defines the gaps between axis objects. For the built-in `subplot` command, the third parameter defines which axis is set as the `CurrentAxes` of the Figure. This option is not available in `tight_subplot` because I personally did not find it useful. Typically, I use the returned axes handles to specify where to add graphics.

Existing axes objects are repositioned when you add a `colorbar`.

I have added a second output argument to `tight_subplot` which provides the output position of the axes so that you can "reset" the axes positions after adding a colorbar.

```
[hax, position] = tight_subplot();

% Add a colorbar which alters the positions
colorbar();

% Now reset the positions back to where they were
set(hax, {'Position'}, pos);
```

Comment: I added an example output of the new `tight_subplot` in the body of the question.