# No Gap Next to Axis Label in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Matlab 2015b or Matlab 2016a.

I would like to have grid lines going across Subplot's spacing between the figures in order to evaluate better two pictures horizontally. 
However, I have a small gap between the two figures at the lower right-hand-side corner because which is misaligning the figures

[image]

where the gap is because of the `10^4` at lower right-hand-side corner. 
I would also like to have horizontal lines going across the spacing between the two figures, but I cannot do it before the gap problem is solved.

Code where the relative alignment is done as described in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35774799/54964) about the thread *Tight subplot with colorbars and subplot's 3rd parameter in Matlab?*

```
data=randi(513,513);
D=mat2gray(pdist(data, 'correlation'));

% Set normalized outer position (x,y,width,height)
ax1=axes('OuterPosition', [0 0.5 0.5 0.5]);
plot(D, 'Parent', ax1);
xlim([0 size(D,2)]);
set(cbar1, 'Visible', 'off')
title('Signal');

ax2=axes('OuterPosition', [0.51 0.5 0.5 0.5]);
plot(D, 'Parent', ax2);
set(ax2, 'XLim', [0, size(D,1)])
axis(ax2, 'square');
title('Corr pdist');
```

### Output of Suever's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35776785/54964)

I tried unsuccessfully change two (2) in `sprintf('%.2g', x)` bigger and smaller

```
ax2 = axes('OuterPosition', [0.51 0.5 0.5 0.5]);
plot(D, 'Parent', ax2);
set(ax2, 'XLim', [0, size(D,1)])
axis(ax2, 'square');
title('Corr pdist');
cbar2 = colorbar(); % ax2 not needed here in brackets
set(ax2, 'XLim', [0 size(D,2)]);
set(cbar2, 'Visible', 'off')
grid minor;
% https://stackoverflow.com/a/35776785/54964
xticks = get(ax2, 'xtick');
labels = arrayfun(@(x)sprintf('%.2g', x), xticks, 'uniform', 0);
set(ax2, 'xticklabels', labels);
```

It gives

[image]

where those ticks are not XMinorTicks but simply ticks (wrongly marked in the picture).
They are zero points at some points in the x-axis. When x-axis gets larger, MATLAB automatically adds new xtick marks but without complete labels. 
I think it would be better to have another symbol than zero there. How can you have some other mark than zero for incomplete labels of xticks?

---

How can you align the 10^4 next to the last number in the second figure?

Comment: You probably can't.  You might consider using custom axis tick labels so the x10^4 doesn't appear.

Comment: Which version of Matlab?  This sounds silly but Mathworks changed the display engine in version 14a I think.  For me (version 15a) subplots self align

Comment: Instead of using `axes('OuterPosition'...` can you just use subplots?

Comment: @Matt go look up his other posts. This is like one continuous question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35770961/tight-subplot-with-colorbars-and-subplots-3rd-parameter-in-matlab/35774799#35774799

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would get the current xtick locations, convert those to strings, and then set the `xticklabels` property of the axes.

```
xticks = get(ax2, 'xtick');
labels = arrayfun(@(x)sprintf('%.2g', x), xticks, 'uniform', 0);
set(ax2, 'xtick', xticks, 'xticklabels', labels);
```

[image]

If you want them to dynamically be computed as the figure changes size (and the xticks get recomputed) you can link this code to the `SizeChangedFcn` of the figure.

```
func = @(varargin)set(ax2,'xticklabels',arrayfun(@(x)sprintf('%.2g',x),get(ax2, 'xtick'),'uni',0));
set(gcf, 'SizeChangedFcn', func)
```

Comment: @masi It looks like you're specifying the wrong axes to get the xticks from. You want to grab xticks from `ax2` in your code! I've updated my answer.

Comment: @Masi Oh ok. You'll want to set the xtickmode to manual so it doesn't try to recompute tick locations. In my answer I've changed it to manually set the xticks to what they were prior to changing the labels.

Comment: Yes, you are right. `set(gca, 'XTickMode', 'manual');` works but it ignores the xminorticks. I think the best solution would be to adjust dynamically the xMinorTicks `set(gca,'XMinorTick', '[somethingDynamic]');`.

Comment: @Masi why not just turn off `xminortick`s?

Comment: Yes, it is best solution now, but it would be better to have them too.

Comment: I have updated my answer to provide a dynamic solution.

Comment: There may be a mistake in `func`, probably `func = @(varargin)set(ax2,'xtick',xticks,'xticklabels',arrayfun(@(x)sprintf('%.2g',x),get(ax2, 'xtick'),'uni',0));`. It ignores `XMinorTick` so it is as good as the current best solution.

Comment: @Masi can you show me what you mean with xminorticks?

Comment: Please, see the last figure in the body. Those small zeros present xminorticks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105292/discussion-between-suever-and-masi).

Comment: I think the dynamic label of xticks in insuffcient space is not possible. Zero is neither possible. So I opened a new thread about replacing zeros with some other symbol than does not cause problems here http://stackoverflow.com/q/35779680/54964