# How to Have Non-Zero Symbol for Incomplete Labels of XTicks in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, calibration

I run into the problem where Matlab 2015b expands the labels of new Xticks when the x-axis gets bigger by using incomplete label, zeros, in the thread [No Gap Next to Axis Label in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35776381/54964)

[image]

The dynamic expansion of incomplete labels of xticks is not possible because there is always cases of insufficient space but only one symbol is needed to mark half between two values. 
The situation is problematic with zeros because I have several calibration points and several systems where the extra zeros are errorprone. 
I would like to have there another symbol.

Example code how to create those incomplete labels of xticks

```
labels = arrayfun(@(x)sprintf('%.2g', x), xticks, 'uniform', 0);
ax2 = axes('OuterPosition', [0.51 0.5 0.5 0.5]); % anything here
xticks = get(ax2, 'xtick'); % https://stackoverflow.com/a/35776785/54964
set(ax2, 'xticklabels', labels); % here the point!
```

Without those incomplete labels of xticks but broader labelling which is worser

```
labels = arrayfun(@(x)sprintf('%.2g', x), xticks, 'uniform', 0);
ax2 = axes('OuterPosition', [0.51 0.5 0.5 0.5]);
xticks = get(ax2, 'xtick'); % https://stackoverflow.com/a/35776785/54964
set(ax2, 'xtick', xticks, 'xticklabels', labels);
```

### Output of Suever's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35780915/54964)

**Beautiful** Small window in the original size with scientific numbering because of `callback();` at the end of the code following

[image]

Medium window

[image]

Code

```
hFig=figure;
data=randi(513,513);
D=mat2gray(pdist(data, 'correlation'));

ax2 = axes('OuterPosition', [0.51 0.5 0.5 0.5]);
plot(D, 'Parent', ax2);
axis(ax2, 'square');
title('Corr pdist');
cbar2 = colorbar(); 
set(ax2, 'XLim', [0 size(D,2)]);
set(cbar2, 'Visible', 'off')
grid minor;
labelconverter = @(x)sprintf('%.2g', x); % https://stackoverflow.com/a/35780915/54964
callback = @(varargin)set(ax2, 'xticklabels', arrayfun(labelconverter, get(ax2, 'xtick'), 'uniform', 0));
set(hFig, 'SizeChangedFcn', callback);
callback(); % necessary for small window
```

---

How can you have another symbol for the incomplete labels of xticks in Matlab?

Comment: The issue here is that you must *draw* the axes prior to getting the tick positions and therefore the labels. So 1) draw axes 2) drawnow 3) get xticks 4) create labels from xticks 5) set xticklabels. You can also use the dynamic answer that I have provided below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the other question, if you want the labels to be updated automatically when you resize things, you'll want to do the following.

```
fig = figure;

% Set large xlimits to demonstrate the issue at hand
ax2 = axes('xlim', [0 1e9]);

% Force a draw event to have the axes determine where the
labelconverter = @(x)sprintf('%.2g', x);
callback = @(varargin)set(ax2, 'xticklabels', arrayfun(labelconverter, get(ax2, 'xtick'), 'uniform', 0));

set(fig, 'SizeChangedFcn', callback);

% Be sure to execute the callback to get new labels prior to figure resize.
callback();
```

As you change the size of your figure, the labels will be changed automatically and the positions will be updated.

**Small Window**

[image]

**Medium Window**

[image]

**Large Window**

[image]

> **Note**: Test this code in isolation to verify that it works, then adapt the idea to your solution. It seems like you're ending up with a lot of complications because your namespace is polluted (for example your examples don't even run because `labels` isn't defined).

Comment: @Masi was the small window the original size? If so, you'll likely need to call `callback()` after everything is drawn because at this point, your'e not making the modification **until** the size of the figure changes.

Comment: @Masi Dude please stop and breathe. I'm not saying that you *should* use those xlims. My answer is *general* and is used to demonstrate the point I'm trying to make. It's not going to be a literal copy/paste to your solution. Please think a little bit before posting. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Adding `callback();` to the end solves the problem. Thank you!