# Linkaxes of Heterogenous Matrixes in Square Control of Matlab?

Tags: matlab, data-visualization

I am trying to have the linked control of two matrices which have different xlims and ylims by `linkaxes()` where there exists an inverse function between the two matrices.
The axes of the matrices (signal `D` / square matrix `D_square`) are `ax2`/`ax4`, respectively. 
The dimensions of the axes are

[image]

The limits of `ax2` are different than those of `ax4`, since `linkaxes()` just *makes all input axes have identical limits*. 
A selection of Fig. ax2 (= zooming an area in the figure) should bring forward appropriate selection in Fig. ax4. 
I think you should tell Matlab how to do it. 
The only difference between the two datasets is that data of `ax2` is the matrix `D`, while the data of `ax4` is the matrix `D_square=squareform(D, 'tomatrix')` which has an inverse transform, `D=squareform(D_square, 'tomatrix')` so it is possible to have a control between the two figures. 
Code

```
data=randi(513,513);
D=mat2gray(pdist(data, 'correlation')); 

% Set normalized outer position (x,y,width,height)
ax2 = axes('OuterPosition', [0.51 0.5 0.5 0.5]);
plot(D, 'Parent', ax2);
axis(ax2, 'square');
title('Corr pdist');
cbar2 = colorbar(); 
set(ax2, 'XLim', [0 size(D,2)]);
set(cbar2, 'Visible', 'off')
grid minor;
% Force a draw event to have the axes determine where the
labelconverter = @(x)sprintf('%.2g', x); % http://stackoverflow.com/a/35780915/54964
callback = @(varargin)set(ax2, 'xticklabels', arrayfun(labelconverter, get(ax2, 'xtick'), 'uniform', 0));
set(hFig, 'SizeChangedFcn', callback);
callback(); % necessary for the original small window and its scientific numbering

%% Problem here!
D_square=squareform(D, 'tomatrix');
ax4 = axes('OuterPosition', [0.51 0 0.5 0.5]);
set(ax4, 'XLim', [0 size(D_square,2)]);
image( D_square, 'Parent', ax4 ); % TODO problem here!
set(gca,'YDir','normal');
colormap('parula'); colorbar;
axis(ax4, 'square');
title('Square Corr pdist');

linkaxes([ax2,ax4], 'x');
```

Output

[image]

where Fig. ax4 gets substituted because lims of `ax4` are substituted by `ax2`, vice versa for `linkaxes([ax4,ax2], 'x');` in the last line.

### Some fixes in Suever's answer

Some changes

- Use `imagesc()` in `him=imagesc( D_square, 'Parent', ax4 );`
- initiate/let things be square by `axis(ax4, 'square');` just after `imagesc()`; not sure why
- unknown about if `linkaxes([ax2,ax4], 'xy');` or just one axis `linkaxes([ax2,ax4], 'x');`

Code

```
data=randi(513,513);
D=mat2gray(pdist(data, 'correlation'));

% Figure out the xrange of your first plot
xrange = [1, numel(D)];

% Set normalized outer position (x,y,width,height)
ax2 = axes('OuterPosition', [0.51 0.5 0.5 0.5]);
plot(D, 'Parent', ax2);
axis(ax2, 'square');
title('Corr pdist');
cbar2 = colorbar(); 
set(ax2, 'XLim', [0 size(D,2)]);
set(cbar2, 'Visible', 'off')
grid minor;
% Force a draw event to have the axes determine where the
labelconverter = @(x)sprintf('%.2g', x); % http://stackoverflow.com/a/35780915/54964
callback = @(varargin)set(ax2, 'xticklabels', arrayfun(labelconverter, get(ax2, 'xtick'), 'uniform', 0));
set(hFig, 'SizeChangedFcn', callback);
callback(); % necessary for the original small window and its scientific numbering

D_square=squareform(D, 'tomatrix');
ax4 = axes('OuterPosition', [0.51 0 0.5 0.5]);
set(ax4, 'XLim', [0 size(D_square,2)]);
him=imagesc( D_square, 'Parent', ax4 ); 
axis(ax4, 'square'); % To let things be square!
set(gca,'YDir','normal');
colormap('parula'); colorbar;
title('Square Corr pdist');

% Set XData AND YData (to keep things square)
set(him, 'XData', xrange, 'YData', xrange); 

linkaxes([ax2,ax4], 'xy');
```

where the problem is

- *to keep things square* by `set(him, 'XData', xrange, 'YData', xrange);`
- and to initiate/let them be square by `axis(ax4, 'square');` just after `imagesc()`; code not working as expected having initiation of square shape too far from plotting for some reason.

I think personally that it may not be possible to have strict control (both x,y axes by `linkaxes([ax2,ax4], 'xy')`) between the two figures. 
I think only one axis (by `linkaxes([ax2,ax4], 'x')` or `linkaxes([ax2,ax4], 'y')`) can be controlled at least because there exists an inverse function. Some empirical evidence

- Output in `linkaxes([ax2,ax4], 'xy');` is two empty figures.
- Output in `linkaxes([ax2,ax4], 'x');` is one figure with some graph and full matrix. Similar with y control.

### Active control of square shape

Here active control of square shape by `set(him, 'XData', xrange, 'YData', xrange);`. 
Outputs with keeping square in original view

[image]

where one full matrix.

### Outputs without keeping square in original view

Disable `set(him, 'XData', xrange, 'YData', xrange);`

[image]

where Fig.ax4 is right. No

### Successful Output from Suever's 2nd edit

Original view in x control by `linkaxes([ax2,ax4], 'x');` and other changes about labels as described in Suever's answer

[image]

where the medium picture is also functional.

---

How can you tell Matlab the relation between the figures in using linkaxes()?
How can you have a linked control between the two figures in Matlab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having issues because the image in your bottom axes is 513 x 513 (xlims = [0.5 513.5]) whereas the xlimits of your top axes [0 131328]. If you need them to be the same, you can simply alter the `XData` and `YData` of your image to be the same as your XLims for your top plot.

```
% Figure out the xrange of your first plot
xrange = [1, numel(D)];

% Set XData AND YData (to keep things square)
him = image( D_square, 'Parent', ax4 );
set(him, 'XData', xrange, 'YData', xrange);
```

Now when you call `linkaxes` (which links XLims) they should move together. You will also need to call `axis(ax4, 'tight')` to refit the axes to the new image data.

I have included a modified version of your code below that *also* keeps the xticklabels the same between the two plots.

```
hFig = figure();

data = randi(513,513);
D = mat2gray(pdist(data, 'correlation'));
D_square = squareform(D, 'tomatrix');

% Set normalized outer position (x,y,width,height)
ax2 = axes('OuterPosition', [0.51 0.5 0.5 0.5]);
plot(D, 'Parent', ax2);
axis(ax2, 'square');
title('Corr pdist');
cbar2 = colorbar();

set(ax2, 'XLim', [0 size(D,2)]);

set(cbar2, 'Visible', 'off')
grid minor;

% Force a draw event to have the axes determine where the
labelconverter = @(x)sprintf('%.2g', x); % http://stackoverflow.com/a/35780915/54964
callback = @(varargin)set(ax2, 'xticklabels', arrayfun(labelconverter, get(ax2, 'xtick'), 'uniform', 0));
set(hFig, 'SizeChangedFcn', callback);

callback(); % necessary for the original small window and its scientific numbering

ax4 = axes('OuterPosition', [0.51 0 0.5 0.5]);

him = imagesc( D_square, 'Parent', ax4 ); % TODO problem here!

% Set the XData and YData of the image
set(him, 'xdata', [1, size(D, 2)], 'ydata', [1, size(D,2)])
set(ax4,'YDir','normal');
colormap('parula');
colorbar;
axis(ax4, 'square');

% Fit the axes to the new XData and YData
axis(ax4, 'tight')
title('Square Corr pdist');

% Link the two together
linkaxes([ax2,ax4], 'x');

% Ensure that the labels ALSO remain the same
linkprop([ax2,ax4], 'XTickLabel')
```

Comment: I think I understand the problem now better. The xlims and ylims are different between the two matrices. There is an inverse function to get `D` matrix from `D_matrix` so we can have the selection of Fig.ax2 in linkaxes() of Fig.ax4. However, I am not sure how I should tell Matlab this relation `D_square=squareform(D)` and `D=squareform(D_matrix)`. I think the image function should be `imagesc` instead of `image` because of a strange problem in debugging.

Comment: I managed to debug one problem down. You need to initiate the square control in the first place in both matrices. Then, comes the control of square shape in both matrices like you describe. Now, it is the main problem at hand: how to tell Matlab about how the selection A in Fig.ax2 should match Fig.ax4.

Comment: @Masi what do you mean by "the selection"?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I mean by selection zooming an area in the figure.

Comment: @Masi I have updated my answer with your code modified to actually work. Also I slipped in the usage of `imagesc` which is a bit less of a pain than `image` in my experience.

Comment: Perfect! I have to open a bounty soon such that I can give you extra reward.  Thank you! I added a final picture of the successful output in the body.