# Background Grid Lines Across Spacing of Figures in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I would like to have vertical/horizontal grid lines across spacing of figures in Matlab 2015b. 
I know that you can have a background image that can be a network of gridlines by `background`, something partial about it at [How do I add a background image to my GUI or figure window?](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/96023-how-do-i-add-a-background-image-to-my-gui-or-figure-window)
However, I think gridlines without a picture would be a better choice

[image]

Example code

```
data=randi(513,513);
D=mat2gray(pdist(data, 'correlation'));

ax2 = axes('OuterPosition', [0.51 0.5 0.5 0.5]);
plot(D, 'Parent', ax2);
set(ax2, 'XLim', [0, size(D,1)])
axis(ax2, 'square');
title('Corr pdist');
cbar2 = colorbar(); 
set(ax2, 'XLim', [0 size(D,2)]);
set(cbar2, 'Visible', 'off')
grid minor;
% Force a draw event to have the axes determine where the
labelconverter = @(x)sprintf('%.2g', x); % https://stackoverflow.com/a/35780915/54964
callback = @(varargin)set(ax2, 'xticklabels', arrayfun(labelconverter, get(ax2, 'xtick'), 'uniform', 0));
set(hFig, 'SizeChangedFcn', callback);
callback(); % necessary for the original small window and its scientific numbering

D_square=squareform(D, 'tomatrix');
ax4 = axes('OuterPosition', [0.51 0 0.5 0.5]);

imshow( D_square ); 
colormap('parula'); colorbar;
axis(ax4, 'square');  
title('Square Corr pdist');
```

where the system is based on relative positions, rather than `subplot` as described in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35774799/54964) about *Tight subplot with colorbars and subplot's 3rd parameter in Matlab?*

Hypothetical methods

- have master figure which has grid lines; embed those two figures there as parent positions; not sure if possible
- assign gridlines function to the function `background`
- have a separate background image which has static gridlines

### Function about Suever's [script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35781967/54964)

```
function [ hFig ] = init_background_grid(thickness)

    %% Background
    hFig=figure;
    backax = axes('Parent', hFig);

    % Ensure that this is below other objects
    uistack(backax, 'bottom');

    % Span the whole figure
    set(backax, 'Position', [0 0 1 1]);

    grid(backax, 'on')

    % Make it invisible except for the grid and
    % ensure it isn't able to be interacted with
    set(backax, 'HitTest', 'off', ...
            'HandleVisibility', 'off', ...
            'GridLineStyle', '-', ...
            'Color', 'none', ...
            'XColor', 'none', ...
            'YColor', 'none')

    % Determine grid spacing with x/y ticks
    % Increase nLines for a finer grid
    nLines = thickness; % 30 default

    set(backax, 'XTick', linspace(0, 1, nLines), ...
            'YTick', linspace(0, 1, nLines));

end
```

---

How can you have grid lines in the background i.e. in the spacing between figures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably just setup an axes that spans your entire figure, then turn on the grid lines, then set the color of the axes to 'none'. A full example is shown below.

```
fig = figure();
backax = axes('Parent', fig);

% Ensure that this is below other objects
uistack(backax, 'bottom');

% Span the whole figure
set(backax, 'Position', [0 0 1 1]);

grid(backax, 'on')

% Make it invisible except for the grid and
% ensure it isn't able to be interacted with
set(backax, 'HitTest', 'off', ...
            'HandleVisibility', 'off', ...
            'GridLineStyle', '-', ...
            'Color', 'none', ...
            'XColor', 'none', ...
            'YColor', 'none')

% Determine grid spacing with x/y ticks
% Increase nLines for a finer grid
nLines = 20;

set(backax, 'XTick', linspace(0, 1, nLines), ...
            'YTick', linspace(0, 1, nLines));
```

[image]

You can then add any plots, uicontrols, etc. on top of this and it should work just fine. It will also handle the case where you decide that you want a different figure color.

Comment: Guarantee he's going to ask that the grid aligns with his plots

Comment: I created a function about your script in the body.